# Change values of a dynamically selected list in R

Tags: r

I have a number of lists in base R, I want to loop over these lists and make a change to the list elements. I want to do this change in one line, hard coding the name of every list is not an option:

```
a <- list(thing1=1:5,
          thing2=6:10)

b <- list(thing1=1:5,
          thing2=6:10)

for(list in c("a","b"){

   an_element <- paste(list,
                       "$thing1",
                      sep="") # i.e "a$thing1"

    assign(an_element,20:25) # change value of element thing1 in lists

}

get("a$thing1") # shows change

a$thing1 # does not show change
```

As the documentation for `assign` shows, object `a` has not been changed. I cannot pass `a` into subsequent functions and expect the values of `thing1` to be as I've changed them. I need a way to make the target of a reassignment operation dynamic, given by a variable.

Comment: are you trying to replace values in `a$thing1` using the string "a$thing1" ?

Comment: your `assign` creates a vector called `a$thing1` (try typing \`a$thing1\`). What exactly are you trying to achieve? There may be a better way than assign.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to change values in an arbitrary object by supplying a string that indicates that object. In my problem, there will be many lists, and I need to operate on those objects over a loop. Editing a list is easy enough, I need to make *which* list is being edited, dynamic, supplied by a loop, say.

Answer (score 1):

using your example:

```
a <- list(thing1=1:5,
          thing2=6:10)
```

There are many ways to loop over the elements of a list:

```
anames <- names(a)
anames
# [1] "thing1" "thing2"
for(i in 1:length(anames)) {
  print(a[[anames[i]]])
}
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5
# [1]  6  7  8  9 10
```

using this index you can set a value too

```
for(i in 1:length(anames)) {
  a[[anames[i]]] <- 5*(i+2)+1:5
  print(a[[anames[i]]])
}
# [1] 16 17 18 19 20
# [1] 21 22 23 24 25
```

or you can directly use the index

```
for(i in 1:length(anames)) {
  a[[i]] <- 5*(i+2)+1:5
  print(a[[anames[i]]])
}
# same result
```

and you can lapply

```
b <- lapply(a, function(x) {
  x+15
})
b$thing1
#[1] 16 17 18 19 20
```

I don't think there is a clean way to do this with assign

Comment: The problem here is we need to work on an arbitrary set of lists. We can't hard code list `a', the lists must be operated on dynamically, as in a loop.

Comment: could "a" be a list with all of your lists in it? You're going to need to refer to the lists at some point and I'm not really sure what methods you find.to be acceptable.

Comment: Yes, that would be fine. A list with the names, or even the lists themselves

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution.

```
a <- list(thing1=1:5,
          thing2=6:10)

b <- list(thing1=1:5,
          thing2=6:10)

c <- list(thing1=1:5,
          thing2=6:10)

for(list in c("a","b","c")){

  assign("tempList",list)

  tempList$thing1 <- 6:10

  assign(list,tempList)

}

a$thing1 # shows change
b$thing1
c$thing1
```

Emphasising here that the goal is to operate on a large number of lists, without having to repeat the line(s) which modify the list, for each list to be worked on. You dynamically assign your active list (active in the loop) to a temporary list of a fix name. Then do you operations on that list. For background, I'm seeking to overwrite the data matrix of a VAR model form the packages "vars". I have a certain forecasting problem which requires modifying the data of a large number of VAR models, and then producing forecasts from them.

Comment: I'm confused about what you mean when you say, "without having to hard code all the names of the lists". Isn't the for loop's use of c("a", "b", "c") a hard coded list of the names of the lists?

Comment: Poorly worded on my part. I mean hard coding the reassignments